# Does order of annoatations matter in @Retryable and @Trace in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

Does order of annotations matter in Spring Boot?

Context: I'm not getting logs for methods which have @Trace added before @Retryable annotation. I'm not getting the trace logs for methods written like this:

```
@Trace
    @Retryable(
            value = { ManagerException.class },
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
    public Object dummy(@NotNull @Valid DummyObject dummyObject){
```

However I get all the logs for methods written in this order

```
@Retryable(
            value = { ManagerException.class },
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
    @Trace
```